# Get request username firebase [VUE]

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, get

I'm trying to setup a database with Firebase which also had a username field. I'm using the identity toolkit from Google (https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/signInWithPassword) to do the sign up and login actions. But as far as I know I can't store a username in the sign up database because I can't alter the tables and stuff. Which is why I made my own Firebase database (see picture, the data in that database is stored through a POST request). What I'm trying to do is get the username through a GET request.

I can setup a connection to my own Firebase database and get an ok response. I'm doing this using the following code:

```
const responseUser = await fetch(
  `https://[firebase-link].firebasedatabase.app/users/${userId}.json`,
  {
    method: "GET",
  }
);
```

This works as I get a response when I log it, with a status 200 (which seems to be a correct connection). In the console.log I can also clearly see the corresponding userId I'm using in the request, which matches the userId in the database. So as far as I know I'm actually finding the correct user in the database, but there is no place where I Caan find the userName. The second screenshot is the response I'm getting. I've tried to open pretty much all options within the response but there's no place I can find the name which is in the database.

I know I'm missing something probably very simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. Can you guys help me out?

[image: My Firebase database][image: console.log response from GET request]

EDIT:
I'm trying to find another way to do it, I'm returning a list of all users (won't be that many anyway) and afterwards I'm using a for loop to go through every entry. See code below:

```
const responseUser = await fetch(
  `https://[firebase-link].firebasedatabase.app/users.json`,
  {
    method: "GET",
  }
);

// console.log(responseUser);

const responseUserData = await responseUser.json();
// console.log("ResponseUserData ===");
// console.log(responseUserData);

for (let userData in responseUserData) {
  let userId = responseData.localId;
  console.log("== userId");
  console.log(userId); // returns the user ID I need to filter the userData on

  console.log("== full user item");
  console.log(userData); // returns the user item, which contains userId and userName
  console.log("---------------------------------");

  // How do I filter to get the userName of userItem with corresponding userId?
}
```

Now all I need to do is to filter the userItem, like I stated in the final comment in my code. How though?

I've tried to filter the following way:

```
const user = responseUserData.filter(user => user.userId === userId)
console.log(user);
```

But that gives me an error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: responseUserData.filter is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the doc for the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch): a call with fetch returns a Promise containing the response (a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object). Then, to extract the JSON body content from the response, the doc indicates that you need to use the [`json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) method, which "returns a Promise which resolves with a JavaScript object that is the result of parsing the body text as JSON".

The doc shows the following example, using twice the [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method (i.e. chaining the Promises) since two Promises are returned, as explained above.

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

---

In your case, since you use `async/await`, the following will do the trick:

```
const response = await fetch(
      `https://[firebase-link].firebasedatabase.app/users/${userId}.json`,
      {
        method: 'GET',
      }
    );

const responseData = await response.json();
console.log(responseData);
console.log(responseData.userName);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried it in both ways you advised me but both times it returns null. I've made a pastebin of my code here (https://pastebin.com/udidv92i). If you could take a look at what I'm doing wrong I'd really appreciate that.
EDIT:
I removed `/${userId}` from the fetch link and that does return the list of users. Although as you can see in my initial screenshot the userId != to the (for me) random value that was generated by adding the user to the database, which holds my userId and userName, any help on that?

Comment: It seems that the value of userId in ${userId} is not what you expect. Can you debug this part? You can manually create a user with a simple id e.g; `abcd` and give try with an hard coded url (i.e. `https://[firebase-link].firebasedatabase.app/users/abcd.json`).

Comment: I tried it in a another way which comes down to the same testing. I couldn't find out how to add a user manually with 2 fields so I copied the random string (which I blacked (red) out and starts with M__qX0) but I then still get a similar response like in the second picture. I'm editing my question in a bit with another options, just need the final step for that.

Comment: Based on your last update you should do `responseUserData.userName`. The same way than in the answer, just the variable name changes.